# Print child elements as ng-options of an AngularJS select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am iterating through an array of food items and printing out a select for each one. I want to populate the options of the select from child elements of the array. I am trying to do it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="food in foodlist"> {{food.name}} 
<select ng-options="unit.title as unit in food.unit" ng-model="unit" ng-change="update()"></select>
{{unit.name}}
</div>   
</div>
```

The foods look like this:

```
{code: 1, name: 'Yoghurt', "unit":[
  {"title":"bottle",
   "gram":"45",
   "max":"100"
   },
   {"title":"cup",
   "gram":"250",
   "max":"12"}
  ]},
```

This prints out the title of each food fine, but prints nothing into the selects.

## [See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/137/)

I guess that I am calling the child elements incorrectly. Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your ng-options. Try this:

```
<select ng-options="unit.title for unit in food.unit" ng-model="unit" ng-change="update()"></select>
```

Using 'as' in your expression will allow you to specify what is displayed as the text part of the option. You still need the 'for' part of the statement which is the variable crated for each item in the collection food.unit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps immensely, and has saved me from something that has been frustrating me for hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options` like: `ng-options="unit.title as unit.title for unit in food.unit"`

Also you can use `ng-init` to avoid empty combo on start:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="food in foodlist">{{food.name}}
        <select
        ng-options="unit.title as unit.title for unit in food.unit"            
        ng-model="unit"            
        ng-change="update()"
        ng-init="unit = food.unit[0].title"
        ></select>{{unit.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/140/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I populated my drop-down menu in this way.

```
<html>
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="direction for direction in directionOptions"></select>

<controller>
var Directions = ['UP', 'DOWN', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT'];
$scope.directionOptions= Directions;
```

You can specify what value you want displayed in the drop-down menu by editing the first 'direction' in the ng-options.